# How can I fix the position of a custom view while rotating it from its anchors in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rotation, android-custom-view

I have a custom view named `MyView` that has two anchors. I would like to be able to rotate this view from its anchors, with one anchor acting as the center of rotation while the user drags the other anchor.

**For simplicity, I have drawn a line, but in reality, I will be drawing something else**. Here are the steps:

- If the user clicks on the view itself, translate the view.
- If the user clicks on one of its anchors, calculate the rotation angle and make the other anchor the center of rotation by using `setPivotX()` and `setPivotY()`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                tapX = event.getX();
                tapY = event.getY();

                if (anchorRect1.contains(tapX, tapY)) {
                    viewState = ViewState.ANCHOR1;
                    setPivotX(anchorRect2.centerX());
                    setPivotY(anchorRect2.centerY());
                } else if (anchorRect2.contains(tapX, tapY)) {
                    viewState = ViewState.ANCHOR2;
                    setPivotX(anchorRect1.centerX());
                    setPivotY(anchorRect1.centerY());
                } else {
                    viewState = ViewState.VIEW;
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                switch (viewState) {
                    //Anchor 1 clicked
                    case ANCHOR1: {
                        float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - anchorRect2.centerY(), getWidth()));
                        setRotation(getRotation() - angle);
                        break;
                    }
                    //Anchor 2 clicked
                    case ANCHOR2: {
                        float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - anchorRect1.centerY(), getWidth()));
                        setRotation(getRotation() + angle);
                        break;
                    }
                    //View Clicked
                    case VIEW: {
                        float deltaX = event.getX() - tapX;
                        float deltaY = event.getY() - tapY;

                        // Transform point
                        PointF transformedPoint = transformPoint(deltaX, deltaY, getRotation());

                        //Perform the rotation
                        setX(getX() + transformedPoint.x);
                        setY(getY() + transformedPoint.y);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of the current output:

[image]

The issue is that when I rotate the view for the first time, it works correctly, but when I rotate it from the other anchor, it jumps to another position. I believe this is because the rotation doesn't affect the position of the view. To fix this, I need to recalculate the new position of the view so that it moves accordingly, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is what I am trying to achieve (created with the GeoGebra tool):

[image]

Additionally, I believe that this issue is not limited to the Android platform as I have faced a similar problem while implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944102/how-to-correctly-rotate-a-qgraphicsitem-around-different-anchors-in-qt-c) feature using the Qt framework.

I've invested a significant amount of time in addressing this issue, and any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

**--------------------Start Edit-----------------------------------**

According to the answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944102/how-to-correctly-rotate-a-qgraphicsitem-around-different-anchors-in-qt-c), it seems like the issue with the current implementation is that the view isn't saving the previous transformation. Every time the pivot point is updated, all the previous transformations are reset, which causes the view to behave incorrectly.

To resolve this issue, we need to chain those transformations (one applied after another). In Qt, this can be achieved by saving the transformations in a list, as in this code:

```
QList<QGraphicsTransform*> trans;


auto angle = qRadiansToDegrees(qAtan2( _anchor2.y() -p.y(), width));
QGraphicsRotation* rot = new QGraphicsRotation;
rot->setOrigin(QVector3D(cp2.x(), cp2.y(), 0));
rot->setAxis(Qt::ZAxis);
rot->setAngle(angle);
trans.push_back(rot);
setTransformations(_trans);
```

Another way to achieve this behavior is to use the [QTransform](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix) class directly. In this case, it's important to set the `isRelative` parameter to true in `setTransform()` so that the transformations are chained together.

```
QTransform t;
auto angle = qRadiansToDegrees(qAtan2(_anchor2.y() -p.y(), width));
t.translate(cp2.x(), cp2.y());
t.rotate(angle);
t.translate(-cp2.x(), -cp2.y());
setTransform(t, true);
```

In Android, the equivalent of the [QTransform](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix) is the [Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix) class. However, unlike QT, the `View` class in Android does not have a `setMatrix()` method. This means that when performing transformations, you cannot simply apply the current matrix to the view, which makes it more difficult to work with.

**-------------------End Edit---------------------------------------**

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/elhaouzi/RotateViewQuestion) to reproduce the issue, and below is the complete code:

MyView.java

```
public class MyView extends View {

    enum ViewState {
        ANCHOR1, ANCHOR2, VIEW
    }

    public static final int RADIUS = 24; // Anchor radius
    public static final int OFFSET = 1;

    private final Paint paint;

    public RectF anchorRect1;
    public RectF anchorRect2;

    private ViewState viewState;

    private float tapX;
    private float tapY;


    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        anchorRect1 = new RectF();
        anchorRect2 = new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        var width = getWidth();
        var height = getHeight();

        //Draw line between anchor points
        canvas.drawLine(
                anchorRect1.centerX(), anchorRect1.centerY(),
                anchorRect2.centerX(), anchorRect2.centerY(), paint);

        //Draw anchor circle
        canvas.drawCircle(anchorRect1.centerX(), anchorRect1.centerY(), RADIUS, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(anchorRect2.centerX(), anchorRect2.centerY(), RADIUS, paint);

        //Draw bounding rect
        canvas.drawRect(OFFSET, OFFSET, width - OFFSET, height - OFFSET, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        //Recompute anchors rect
        anchorRect1.set(
                OFFSET, h /2f - RADIUS + OFFSET,
                2*RADIUS, h /2f + RADIUS - OFFSET
        );

        anchorRect2.set(
                w - 2*RADIUS, h /2f - RADIUS + OFFSET,
                w - OFFSET, h /2f + RADIUS - OFFSET
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        // Measure exactly
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                tapX = event.getX();
                tapY = event.getY();

                // Anchor 1 clicked
                if (anchorRect1.contains(tapX, tapY)) {
                    viewState = ViewState.ANCHOR1;
                    setPivotX(anchorRect2.centerX());
                    setPivotY(anchorRect2.centerY());
                }
                // Anchor 2 clicked
                else if (anchorRect2.contains(tapX, tapY)) {
                    viewState = ViewState.ANCHOR2;
                    setPivotX(anchorRect1.centerX());
                    setPivotY(anchorRect1.centerY());
                }
                // View body clicked
                else {
                    viewState = ViewState.VIEW;
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                switch (viewState) {
                    //Anchor 1 clicked
                    case ANCHOR1: {
                        float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - anchorRect2.centerY(), getWidth()));
                        setRotation(getRotation() - angle);
                        break;
                    }
                    //Anchor 2 clicked
                    case ANCHOR2: {
                        float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - anchorRect1.centerY(), getWidth()));
                        setRotation(getRotation() + angle);
                        break;
                    }
                    //View Clicked
                    case VIEW: {
                        float deltaX = event.getX() - tapX;
                        float deltaY = event.getY() - tapY;

                        // Transform point
                        PointF transformedPoint = transformPoint(deltaX, deltaY, getRotation());

                        //Perform the rotation
                        setX(getX() + transformedPoint.x);
                        setY(getY() + transformedPoint.y);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private PointF transformPoint(float x, float y, float degree) {
        //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
        double radian = Math.toRadians(degree);
        float xp = (float) (x*Math.cos(radian) - y*Math.sin(radian));
        float yp = (float) (x*Math.sin(radian) + y*Math.cos(radian));
        return new PointF(xp, yp);
    }
}
```

FixedPosLayout.java

```
public class FixedPosLayout extends ViewGroup {

    public FixedPosLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedPosLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixedPosLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);

            FixedPosLayout.LayoutParams params =
                    (FixedPosLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int left = params.x;
            int top = params.y;

            child.layout(left, top,
                    left + child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    top + child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Measure this view
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Measure children
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);

            FixedPosLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    (FixedPosLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int childWidthMeasureSpec =
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            int childHeightMeasureSpec =
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y) {
            super(width, height);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FixedPosLayout fixedPosLayout = findViewById(R.id.fixedPosLayout);

        MyView myView = new MyView(this);

        FixedPosLayout.LayoutParams params = new FixedPosLayout.LayoutParams(300, 80, 200, 400);
        fixedPosLayout.addView(myView, params);
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<com.abdo.rotateviewquestion.FixedPosLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fixedPosLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: When you rotate the view around different pivots, you get different results (obviously). So, when you change the pivot, you have to translate the view to compensate for this. To calculate the exact translation needed, you need to use some math like sines and cosines. Google (or ask ChatGPT) about rotation matrices if you don't know what that's about.

Comment: Thank you, @LevLeontev I know about matrix rotation, but I'm unsure how it can be applied to address my current problem.

Comment: Your expectation looks like move one point and update its coordinate. I don't sure why need to use rotation?

Comment: I believe it would be best to work the movements through [Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix) operations. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31234875/6287910) question/answer may help.

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp! After performing the required calculations using the `Matrix` class. I cannot find a `View::setMatrix()` method to apply the new matrix to the view! How can I tell the view to use the new matrix? Additionally, I have also made some updates to the question, which you may want to check out.

Comment: There is no _setMatrix_ method. When you rotate/translate/scale you are operating on internal values that are used by the view to draw. [_View#getMatrix()_](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getMatrix()) will give you access to this matrix, but you should not need to directly modify it or replace it with one of your own.

Comment: _ImageViews_ do, however, have an optional matrix. See [ImageView#setImageMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix)). If you want your own matrix, you can take a look at how _ImageView_ does it or use an _ImageView_.

Comment: You can also use a matrix with the canvas: See [Canvas#setMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#setMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix)) although _getMatrix()_ has a caveat for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thank you, @Cheticamp! I attempted to add `Matrix` property into `MyView` class and then using it inside `onDraw` by starting with `canvas.concat(matrix)`. However, I faced some issues. When I attempt to rotate the view, only the view appears to rotate while the viewport remains unaffected, causing the view to become invisible (out of its viewport).

Comment: The matrix will effect all drawing while the matrix operation is applied. It sounds like the code is misapplying or miscalculating the rotation although it is difficult to know from what you say. You may want to consider taking a look at online tutorials about canvas and matrix operations and, maybe, set up a small project to test things out.

Comment: I think I see what you mean about "out of its viewport." This is probably the clipping that occurs when you define the dimensions of your view but then move outside of those dimensions. You can make the boundary of the view larger to hold all possible variations or you can set `android:clipChildren="false"` to the view's parent view group.

Comment: You may want to scratch `android:clipChildren="false"`. It will look OK, but you will have trouble with touches that appear to be within the view but actually fall outside it and can't be detected by the view without some machinations. You would have to detect touches in the parent view group which you may not want to do. Just be aware of this potential pitfall.